# Geth Curl parameter id

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

Whilst going through the documentation for using [JSON RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC), 1 of the parameters hasn't been explained. What is the purpose of id? Is it specific to the type of RPC curl request being made?

For e.g.

> id=67

`curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"web3_clientVersion","params":[],"id":67}'`

> id=64

`curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"web3_sha3","params":["0x68656c6c6f20776f726c64"],"id":64}'`

However it doesn't look like there is a standard id for particular call either. So I was left confused about the purpose behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a standard JSON-RPC field.

According to [the specification](https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification)

> id
>
> An identifier established by the Client that MUST contain a String, Number, or NULL value if included. If it is not included it is
>   assumed to be a notification. The value SHOULD normally not be Null
>   [1](https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification) and Numbers SHOULD NOT contain fractional parts [2]
>
> The Server MUST reply with the same value in the Response object if
>   included. This member is used to correlate the context between the two
>   objects.
>
> (1) The use of Null as a value for the id member in a Request object
>   is discouraged, because this specification uses a value of Null for
>   Responses with an unknown id. Also, because JSON-RPC 1.0 uses an id
>   value of Null for Notifications this could cause confusion in
>   handling.
>
> (2) Fractional parts may be problematic, since many decimal fractions
>   cannot be represented exactly as binary fractions.

You're not guaranteed to get your answers back in the order you asked for them; the id is to help you sort that out.

Comment: Thanks. So basically it like the sequence number used in TCP connection message payload to now which request is this response corresponding to.